# Intermittent Qtdeploy Failures in Go

Tags: qt, go, qt5

I'm running Windows 10 x64 and am having an issue with when I try to build my app with:
qtdeploy test desktop
or
qtdeploy build desktop

I get the error listed below intermittently. I usually am able to compile if I try a few more times and sometimes it doesn't happen at all. I'm using VScode as my IDE btw. I also have my project living on a DropBox directory. It doesn't seem to matter if syncing is on or off. Any help or clues anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated!!

The most notable part of the error:

```
wm/sbs/launch/cancellations/ui
wm/sbs/launch/cancellations
# wm/sbs/launch/cancellations
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running g++ failed: exit status 1
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Go env:

```
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\aellis4\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\aellis4\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\aellis4\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\aellis4\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.21.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\aellis4\Dropbox\WM Projects\Cancellations\Source\Cancellation Process 2.0 - TEST6\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\aellis4\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1414384863=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

QtSetup check:

```
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="running: 'qtsetup check windows' [docker=false] [vagrant=false]"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOOS:                        'windows'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOARCH:                      'amd64'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOVERSION:                   'go1.21.3'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOROOT:                   *  'C:\\Program Files\\Go'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOPATH:                   *  'C:\\Users\\aellis4\\go'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOBIN:                       'C:\\Users\\aellis4\\go\\bin'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="GOMOD:                       'C:\\Users\\aellis4\\Dropbox\\WM Projects\\Cancellations\\Source\\Cancellation Process 2.0 - TEST6\\go.mod'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_HASH:                     'v0.0.0-20200817163748-494d2f8c1ebe'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_API:                      ''"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_VERSION:               *  '5.13.0'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_DIR:                      'C:\\Qt'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_STUB:                     'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_DEBUG:                    'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_QMAKE_DIR:                ''"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_WEBKIT:                   'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_STATIC:                   'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_GEN_GO:                   'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_GEN_OPENGL:               'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_GEN_QUICK_EXTRAS:         'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_RESOURCES_BIG:            'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_NOT_CACHED:               'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_DEBUG_CONSOLE:            'false'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_MSYS2:                 *  'true'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_MSYS2_DIR:                'C:\\msys64\\mingw64'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_MSYS2_ARCH:            *  'amd64'"
time="2023-10-20T14:57:44-04:00" level=info msg="QT_MSYS2_STATIC:          *  'true'"
```

I have no idea where to start from here. I tried reinstalling the msys2 version of the zstd library but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out my issue. The docs for therecipe/qt state you don't have to use msys2 to setup/install the binding or deploy/compile your app if you want to compile a static application. I'm not having much luck using the command prompt within VSCode. I'm having much more consistent success just using msys2 to setup/install the binding as well as compiling my app. It seems through the default command prompt in VScode there's difficulty finding the zstd library. This is my guess.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).